# Trying to get REST service running on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, rest

I have created a REST server under ASP.NET and I can't figure out the url to bring up the service. I am running under VS 2010 using it's built in web server. I believe it is actually running (VS 2010 starts up fine). But every combination I can think of for a url doesn't bring it up.

**Update:** Please take a look at the file http://www.windward.net/temp/RestUnderAspDotNet.zip - I have two solutions in there. The one at src\update runs fine as a REST server. I have pretty much the same code at inetpub\wwwroot\update and while it runs, I can't find a url that talks to it. I tried every variation of http://localhost:56469/update/App_Code/RestServiceImpl.svc/test I could think of and get either 403 or 404.

Any idea why? (I do not want any security on this - anyone will be able to hit it once it's up.)

App_Code\IRestServiceImpl.cs:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestServiceImpl
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/version", Method = "POST")]
    XmlElement GetVersion(XmlElement stats);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/test", Method = "GET")]
    string GetTest();
}
```

App_Code\RestServiceImpl.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="RestServiceImpl" CodeBehind="RestServiceImpl.svc.cs" %>
```

App_Code\RestServiceImpl.cs:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Xml;

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements
    (RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
{
    public XmlElement GetVersion(XmlElement stats)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("update");
        root.SetAttribute("version", "11.0.13.0");
        doc.AppendChild(root);
        return doc.DocumentElement;
    }

    public string GetTest()
    {
        return "update server is running";
    }
}
```

Relevant part of web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="RestServiceImpl">
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
            <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="webBinding">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RestServiceImpl">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webBinding">
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Any idea what the url is to bring up the /test GET?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. I have this also on my blog at [Windward Wrocks](http://blogs.windward.net/davidt/2012/04/03/creating-an-aps-net-rest-web-app/) with screenshots. Here's the solution w/o screenshots:

1. Install the [WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd) (requires .NET 4.0).
2. Create a WCF service. This is a New “Project…” not a “Web Site…”. And it is under the general “Visual C#” templates, not “WCF”!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
http://localhost:whateverportVSgivesyou/RestServiceImpl.svc/test
```

If the VS webserver is running you should see a system tray icon for it, and if you hover over it you'll see the port it's running on...

Comment: Both http://localhost:56469/update/RestServiceImpl.svc/test (the website is update) and http://localhost:56469/RestServiceImpl.svc/test return a 404 error. Any suggestions on how I track down what the url should be?

Comment: Turns out the problem was the project creation wizard put the code under App_Code and IIS will not allow direct calls of code in that folder.